# Multi-level conditional printing with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, formatting, grouping

Earlier this week I asked a question about Conditional Printing with XSLT and received a very helpful answer from helderdarocha. Unfortunately, it turns out that the answer I need is slightly more complicated than I originally thought. Following his instructions, and using the Muenchian method for control breaks, I put together a new example of what I need to do.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group>
    <person>
        <datum type='medium'>Cartoon</datum>
        <datum type='firstname'>Fred</datum>
        <datum type='lastname'>Flintstone</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type='medium'>Cartoon</datum>
        <datum type='firstname'>Wilma</datum>
        <datum type='lastname'>Flintstone</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type='medium'>TV</datum>
        <datum type='firstname'>Luke</datum>
        <datum type='lastname'>Duke</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type='medium'>TV</datum>
        <datum type='firstname'>Daisy</datum>
        <datum type='lastname'>Duke</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type='medium'>Reality</datum>
        <datum type='firstname'>George</datum>
        <datum type='lastname'>Bush</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type='medium'>Reality</datum>
        <datum type='firstname'>Barbara</datum>
        <datum type='lastname'>Bush</datum>
    </person>
</group>
```

And here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="medium" match="person" use="datum[@type='medium']"/>
    <xsl:key name="lastname" match="person" use="//person/datum[@type='lastname']"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="person">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="datum[@type='firstname']"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="group">
        <table border="1">
            <xsl:for-each select="person[count(. | key('medium', datum[@type='medium'])[1]) = 1]/datum[@type='medium']">
                <xsl:sort/>
                <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="//person[count(. | key('lastname', //person/datum[@type='lastname'])[1]) = 1]/datum[@type='lastname']">
                    <xsl:sort/>
                    <tr bgcolor="#ccffcc">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//person[datum[@type='lastname'] = current()]">
                        <xsl:sort select="datum[@type='firstname']"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my output:

[image]

But this is what I'm attempting:

[image]

And, I'm assuming my problem is this line here: `<xsl:for-each select="//person[count(. | key('lastname', //person/datum[@type='lastname'])[1]) = 1]/datum[@type='lastname']">`

I believe I'm not formatting the xpath correctly, but, unfortunately, my understanding of XPath is still relatively weak... My assumption is I need to move that '= 1' check somewhere else but am not sure how to do this.

As always, any and all clues appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code and data.  Put the actual code and data in your post, formatted as code.

Comment: When I do, it tells me the code is formatted incorrectly and then won't let me post. Believe me, I would have preferred to do that.

Comment: Paste your code into a text editor, convert all tabs to 4 spaces, indent everything 4 spaces, then paste into the SO editing window with a blank line above and below the code.

Comment: _What_ tells you the code is formatted incorrectly? SO does not check code format.

Comment: Stack Overflow is what told me and wouldn't let me post...

Comment: Do you have access to xslt 2.0 and xpath 2.0?

Comment: If you really, really aren't able to edit your post with the code, head on over to http://xsltransform.net/, add your XML/XSLT to that, save it, and post the link there. Then maybe someone will be able to edit the question for you, and copy and paste the code in. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, Tim. That's was a helpful suggestion. Unfortunately, xsltranform.net won't let me save anything... :( Checked for logins or anything else I can think of... nothing. Still trying.

Comment: I loaded your code images into an OCR software and it recognized everything without errors (except for the underlined code, which was easy to replace). You can try something like that next time if your code refuses to print in Stack Overflow :D

Comment: Thanks, helderarocha, I do appreciate that. :) The only thing I can tell you for certain is, that the post you originally helped me with, it wouldn't accept the XSLT no matter what I did. And on this post, it wouldn't accept the XML. Add to that work deadlines and SO's 90 minute post "bug" and things got a little frusterating...

@ Tim C

For some reason, XSL Transform won't save on my work computer. Works fine on my home box...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've started off correctly by defining a key for the "medium"

```
<xsl:key name="medium" match="person" use="datum[@type='medium']" />
```

But for your "multi-level" key, you are grouping "lastname" within each "medium". In XSLT 1.0, this means you need to use a concatenated key, like so

```
<xsl:key name="medium-lastname" 
         match="person" 
         use="concat(datum[@type='medium'], '|', datum[@type='lastname'])" />
```

Note the `'|'` separator here can be anything, just as long as it does not appear in any of the "medium" or "lastname" values.

So, you then start off by getting the distinct "medium" values like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="person[generate-id() = generate-id(key('medium', datum[@type='medium'])[1])]" 
     mode="medium" />
```

I am using the generate-id method here, but you could use the count method as you have done. Note the use of "mode" here. Because I am using **xsl:apply-templates** I will end up with multiple templates matching **person** elements, so the mode will distinguish between them.

With this "medium" template, you would then get the distinct "lastname" entries, but using the concatenated key like so (as applied to all elements in the current group, which are accessed by the "medium" key):

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="key('medium', datum[@type='medium'])
            [generate-id() = generate-id(key('medium-lastname', concat(datum[@type='medium'], '|', datum[@type='lastname']))[1])]" 
     mode="lastname" />
```

Finally, within the "lastname" template, you would get all the **person** elements in the group using the concatenated key again:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="key('medium-lastname', concat(datum[@type='medium'], '|', datum[@type='lastname']))" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="medium" match="person" use="datum[@type='medium']" />
    <xsl:key name="medium-lastname" match="person" use="concat(datum[@type='medium'], '|', datum[@type='lastname'])" />

    <xsl:template match="group">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="person[generate-id() = generate-id(key('medium', datum[@type='medium'])[1])]" mode="medium" />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person" mode="medium">
        <tr class="medium">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="datum[@type='medium']" /></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('medium', datum[@type='medium'])[generate-id() = generate-id(key('medium-lastname', concat(datum[@type='medium'], '|', datum[@type='lastname']))[1])]" mode="lastname" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person" mode="lastname">
        <tr class="lastname">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="datum[@type='lastname']" /></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('medium-lastname', concat(datum[@type='medium'], '|', datum[@type='lastname']))" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="datum[@type='firstname']" /></td>
        </tr> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this XML

```
<group>
    <person>
        <datum type="medium">Cartoon</datum>
        <datum type="firstname">Fred</datum>
        <datum type="lastname">Flintstone</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type="medium">Cartoon</datum>
        <datum type="firstname">Wilma</datum>
        <datum type="lastname">Flintstone</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type="medium">Cartoon</datum>
        <datum type="firstname">Barney</datum>
        <datum type="lastname">Rubble</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type="medium">TV</datum>
        <datum type="firstname">Daisy</datum>
        <datum type="lastname">Duke</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type="medium">TV</datum>
        <datum type="firstname">George</datum>
        <datum type="lastname">Bush</datum>
    </person>
</group>
```

Then the following is output

```
<table>
   <tr class="medium">
      <td>Cartoon</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="lastname">
      <td>Flintstone</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Fred</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Wilma</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="lastname">
      <td>Rubble</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Barney</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="medium">
      <td>TV</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="lastname">
      <td>Duke</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Daisy</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="lastname">
      <td>Bush</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>George</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: OK, followup question: how do we achieve the exact same results if, in my original XML, there is no firstname/lastname fields and, instead, just a single name field that looks something like this: <datum type='name'>Fred Flintstone</datum>. In this case, how do I split it so that 'Last Name' still breaks as I need it?

Comment: Assuming just a single space, so it is literally "firstname lastname", you can use the "substring-before" and "substring-after" functions. For example, to get the last name do `substring-after(datum[@type='name'], ' ')`

Answer (score 2):

The key here is to use `<xsl:for-each-group>` to group by medium, then by lastname. This following should work. You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaEM/3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table border="1">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="/group/person" group-by="datum[@type='medium']">
                <tr bgcolor="#cccccc"><td><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></td></tr>

                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="datum[@type='lastname']">
                    <tr bgcolor="#ccffcc"><td><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></td></tr>

                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="./datum[@type='firstname']"/></td></tr>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Mind OP's XSLT version.

Comment: Thanks. :) This works fine on XSL Transform, but not on the tools I used to test it. So, Micheal is right, not the correct version for me.